# How to create a multiindex chart in Pandas that combines categories and numericals

Tags: python, pandas

This is a tricky one for me so bear me out. I'm creating a daily dataset that compiles units using timestamps.

```
day of the week month   day hour    week of year    units
Monday          January 3   16      1               1
Monday          January 3   19      1               1
Tuesday         January 4   21      1               1
Tuesday         January 4   22      1               1
Wednesday       January 5   23      1               1

Monday          January 10  16      2               1
Monday          January 10  19      2               1
Tuesday         January 11  21      2               1
Tuesday         January 11  22      2               1
Wednesday       January 12  23      2               1
```

The various columns are created by using Pandas' excellent time functions and it is relatively trivial to create pivot plots based on a single column, such as day (date of the month), month, hour or even day of the week (thanks to this excellent code sample although lord knows where I found it on SO).

```
cats = [ 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']

from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

cat_type = CategoricalDtype(categories=cats, ordered=True)
df['day of the week'] = df['day of the week'].astype(cat_type)
```

As the dataset increases in size, what I'd like to be able to do is pivot on both say week of year and day of the week.

```
                                 units
week of year    day of the week 
1               Friday           15.2
                Monday           22.8
2               Friday           19.0
3               Thursday         28.0
```

Unfortunately, when I perform pd.pivot_table using week_of_year (numeric) and then categorical (day_of_the_week) I can get the numeric column, but lose the ordering of the categorical.

I'd also like to be able to be able visualise units trend over time (as in week as well as by day of the week.

My head says create matrix plot by week but that misses out the time (day of the week dimension).

Any ideas? I'm not necessarily looking for a solution, although I'll happily write this up if I fix it as I can't see this as a unique problem.

Update: I have a solution in my head in the way I'd solve this in Excel. I'd select day_of_the_week as row (and then sort), pick the numerical (week_of_year) as column, aggregate units as necessary and then plot.

Answer (score 1):

With the sample data and code you provided, you could try this:

```py
new_df = (
    df.groupby(["week of year", "day of the week"]).sum().drop(columns=["day", "hour"])
)
new_df = new_df[new_df["units"] > 0]
```

So that:

```py
print(new_df)
# Ouput
                              units
week of year day of the week       
1            Monday               2
             Tuesday              2
             Wednesday            1
2            Monday               2
             Tuesday              2
             Wednesday            1
```