# How to turn dataframe with categorical rows and numerical columns into coherent chart (sparkline like)

Tags: python, pandas

After a bit of wrangling, I've got a dataframe that sort of looks like how it needs to be, with rows representing days of the week, and columns as weeks as they progress. I'd like to present each day as a timeseries plot, almost like a sparkline - but not sure how to do it.

(Here's my original question and thinking: [How to create a multiindex chart in Pandas that combines categories and numericals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780746/how-to-create-a-multiindex-chart-in-pandas-that-combines-categories-and-numerica))

The data as it stands:

```
week of year    1       2       3
Monday          22.8    0.0     22.8
Tuesday         7.6     0.0     22.8
Wednesday       30.4    19.0    19.0
Thursday        15.2    28.0    0.0
Friday          15.2    19.0    0.0
Saturday        15.2    19.0    0.0
Sunday          0.0     26.6    0.0
```

Update: I do wish I had a working license to Excel to give rough idea of what I'm thinking of. I'm using Numbers and well, it's not Excel. (Unless someone can prove me stupid yet again).

[image]

This would be the line (except the gaps) to represent Wednesday's data. I do anticipate that I can fill the gaps over time using averaging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.relplot(data=df.melt(id_vars='week of year'),
            y='value', x='variable',
            kind='line', row='week of year',
            height=1, aspect=4,
           )
```

output:

[image: relplot]

Or with pure matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=len(df), sharex=True)

for i, (name, s) in enumerate(df.set_index('week of year').iterrows()):
    axes[i].plot(s)
    axes[i].set_title(name)
```

output:

[image: matplotlib]

Comment: Mr/Miss Mozway, that is an excellent answer. I knew it wouldn't be difficult, but I've been out of practice with Pandas and relevant visualisation libraries. Matplotlib output looks better, but I still have nightmares about using it. Seaborn has its quirks but much simpler. 

At least I can now concentrate on things that I'm comfortable with, such as handling missing data. 

Have a good day, sir.