# How to change dimension of Seaborn relplot in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

Much kudos to @mozway for helping me realise a pet project that I've been playing with. I am now looking to determine which parameter to tweak the output from chart.

You can see previous queries here:

[How to create a multiindex chart in Pandas that combines categories and numericals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780746/how-to-create-a-multiindex-chart-in-pandas-that-combines-categories-and-numerica)

And why all praise to @mozway for helping me visualise the data.

I had to tweak his/her approach only because I'm a little rusty on Pandas, but essentially the same.

```
df2 = df.T.reset_index().melt(id_vars="week of year")
```

Which produced this...

```
    week of year    variable    value
0   1               Monday      22.8
1   2               Monday      0.0
2   3               Monday      22.8
3   1               Tuesday     7.6
```

...And so on

Then used Mozway's approach to plotting (answer here: [How to turn dataframe with categorical rows and numerical columns into coherent chart (sparkline like)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70785452/how-to-turn-dataframe-with-categorical-rows-and-numerical-columns-into-coherent))

```
sns.relplot(data=piv6,
            y='value', x='variable',
            kind='line', row='week of year',
            height=1, aspect=10)
```

Which produced this:

[image]

Pretty much spot-on. And this is my fault, but I'd like to increase the vertical dimension of the plot so I can better understand the change over time.

Answer (score 1):

You are using seaborn to generate those graphs, so the best thing you can do is to add:

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(14,10)})
```

If you are using plotlib to generate those graph, then:

```
fig = matplotlib.pyplot.gcf() 
fig.set_size_inches(18.5, 10.5)
```

You can change the figure size as you would like.

Comment: It isn't playing ball at the moment, but thank you for replying so quickly. I'm very out of practice. Have a gud 'un

Comment: If you are using matplotlib, I have added additional codes in my comment. One of them should work fine.